# Maximization of vector norm under a quadratic convex inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms

I need help for the following problem:

$$
\max_x x^Tx\quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad x^TAx+b^Tx\leq c,
$$
where A is symmetric, square and positive semidefinite, c is a real scalar and b is a real vector.

I tried to solve it with the KKT conditions, but I get stuck at the point where I have to determine the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$.
My steps look like this
1. Define
$$
H(x,\lambda)=x^Tx-\lambda (x^TAx+b^Tx-c)
$$
2. Get a candidate of the optimal solution $x^*$ via
$$
\dfrac{\delta H}{\delta x}=2x^*-\lambda (2Ax^*+b)=0,
$$
which leads to
$$  
2(I-\lambda A)x^*=\lambda b  
$$
and assume we choose $\lambda$ so that $I-\lambda A$ is nonsingular I get
$$
x^*=\frac{1}{2}(I-\lambda A)^{-1}\lambda b
$$ 
3. I try to determine $\lambda > 0$ by
$$
(x^*)^TAx^*+b^Tx^*\leq c
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\lambda^2}{4} b^T(I-\lambda A)^{-1}A(I-\lambda A)^{-1}b + \frac{\lambda}{2}b^T(I-\lambda A)^{-1}b \leq c
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\lambda}{2} b^T(I-\lambda A)^{-1}[\frac{\lambda}{2}A(I-\lambda A)^{-1} + I]b \leq c
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\lambda}{2} b^T(I-\lambda A)^{-1}[\frac{\lambda}{2}A + (I-\lambda A)](I-\lambda A)^{-1}b \leq c
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\lambda}{2} b^T(I-\lambda A)^{-1}[(I-\frac{\lambda}{2} A)](I-\lambda A)^{-1}b \leq c
$$

And that is the point where I am stuck...
Does someone have an idea how I could continue?

Comment: In the KKT conditions you have $\lambda g(x) = 0$ (where $g$ is the inequality constraint).

Comment: Note also that you have to minimize $-x^Tx$. So, your function $H$ should be $H(x,\lambda) = -x^Tx - \ldots$. This ensures that the matrix to invert is indeed invertible since $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  
I used the KKT conditions on Wikipedia. There you can also maximize a function, thats why I used $\max_x x^Tx$ instead of $\min_x x^Tx$, but I will try it with minimization and using the condition you proposed.

Comment: Oh yeah, I am sorry. Your signs are ok.

Comment: Do you want to solve that problem for particular given $A,b,c$ or are you looking for some abstract solutions?

Comment: That problem is unbounded, if $A$ has a rank deficit.

Comment: No, right now I dont have any particular $A, b, c$, but they are somehow related, e.g. $A=D^TD$ and $b=D^Te$. I am looking for a more abstract solution though.

Comment: Why is the problem unbounded if $A$ has a rank deficit?
I get that I could choose $x$ as the vector which is in $A$ nullspace so that $x^TAx=0$ but there would still be the constraint that $b^Tx\leq c$, right?

Comment: if you are writing to me, you should include @user251257 somewhere. otherwise I won't get notified. as for your question. let $g(x) = x^T A x + b^T x$, which is convex, and $y$ its minimum. Either we have $g(y) >c$ and the problem is not feasible, or we have $g(y)\le c$. Notice that $g(y+z) = g(y) + z^T \nabla g(y) + 1/2 z^T \nabla^2 g(y) z$. Since $y$ is a minimum, we have $\nabla g(y) = 0$. If $\nabla^2 g(y) = A$ has rank deficit, there is some $z\ne 0$ with $Az=0$ and the line $y+tz$ is unbounded and feasible.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks! I dont get your equation for $g(y+z)$ but a similar one and that makes sense. So my problem only has a solution if the minimum of $g(x)$ is smaller than $c$ and $A$ has full rank?

Comment: @RastaP $\le$, yes. Then, with little bit theory, (at least) one maximizer lies on the boundary, that is $g = c$.

Comment: @user251257    Thanks again! Now I am quite close to the soluton I think. I would say $x$ has to point in the direction of a unit-norm eigenvector $v$ corresponding either to the smallest $\lambda_{min}$ or largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}$, so that $x=\alpha v$ and then I get a scalar quadratic equation, which I can solve for (a hopefully real) $\alpha$ that maximizes $x^Tx=\alpha^2$.

Comment: @RastaP oh my bad, I was silly. $g$ need not have a minimum. It depends on whether $b$ is orthogonal to the null space of $A$ or not. I am really sorry.

Comment: @user251257 Hmm, I dont really get that. But if I assume $A$ is positive definite, i.e has full rank, $A$ won't have a nullspace and $g(x)$ has a minimum, right? Then I can find the maximum norm by using the eigenvalues and -vectors.

Comment: @RastaP I post an answer. Basically you need some arguments to reduce it to the positive definite case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the data are at least such that the problem is feasible. Let $g(x) = x^T A x + b^T x$ for every $x$. Let $\ker A$ denote the null space of $A$.

There are two cases.

**Case 1:**

If $A$ has rank deficit, then the feasible set is unbounded and thus the problem is unbounded. 
Here again we have two cases.
Let $b = b_0 + b_1$ where $b_0\in\ker A$ and $b_1$ is in the image (orthogonal to $\ker A$).

*Sub case 1:* $b_0 \ne 0$.

Then, for every $t \ge 0$ we have
$$ g(x - tb_0) = g(x) - t\|b_0\|^2 \le g(x). $$
So, if there is a feasible point $y$, then the ray $y-tb_0$ is also feasible. As it is unbounded, the problem is unbound.

*Sub case 2:* $b_0=0$.

Let $u\in\ker A\setminus\{0\}$. Then, we have $g(x + u) = g(x)$ for any $x$. Thus, the feasible set contains at least a line and is unbounded again.

**Case 2:**

Let $A$ be positive definite. Notice that the minimum $y$ of $g$ is feasible. Thus, the feasible set is in fact the ellipsis $y+E$ with $E = \{ u \mid u^T A u \le r^2 \}$ and $r = \sqrt{c - g(y) }$.
In particular we have
$$ \max_{g(x)\le c} \| x \| = \max_{u\in E} \| y+u \| = \max_{\|v\|\le r} \| y + A^{-1/2} v\|. $$

I don't see an analytical solution in case of $y\ne 0$.
In case $A, b, c$ are given, one can at least (try to) solve it with numerical methods. We can also obtain following non-trivial lower bound. Let $N$ be an $n\times (n-1)$ matrix whose columns are an orthonormal basis of the orthogonal space of $y$.
Then, for $B = N^T A N$ we have
$$ \max_{u^T A u \le r^2} \|y + u \| \ge \|y\| + \max_{w^T B w \le r^2} \|w\|. $$
The solution of right hand side is given by an eigenvector $w^*$ to the least eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $B$ with $\|w^*\| = r/\sqrt{\lambda_1}$.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the detailed solution, but I have one more question. Since $||y+u||\leq ||y|| + ||u||$, is it possible to just look for $$\max||u||\quad s.t.\quad u^TAu=c-g(y)?$$

Comment: @RastaP: It wouldn't be the same. If $y\ne 0$ the problem is rather difficult and at least I don't see an analytical solution.

Comment: @RastaP: If you need some theoretical result. You get a non-trivial lower bound, if you restrict $u$ to the orthogonal space of $y$.